# UWP Data Binding with EF7 (EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I've written a simple Windows 10 UWP application that presents the user with a ListView of data bound to a SQLite database via EF7.  I took a lot of the starting code from the Microsoft Getting Started on Universal Windows Platform site.

The binding is done in a ViewModel like this:

```
using (var db = new ArtistContext())
{
    lstArtists.ItemsSource = db.Artists.ToList();
}
```

This works fine for displaying the database table.

I then have a second Page (displayed as a modal dialog over the first), which allows the user to add a record to the database table.  This works fine, and I can see the record is added to the database.

But, once the user closes the dialog, I can't get the original view to update to show the change in the database.  I know from WPF development that the databinding for the ListView should really be to an ObservableCollection rather than ToList() from the table. However, I'm drawing a complete blank on how to convert the DBSet coming from the data context into an ObservableCollection, and how to ensure the UI is notified of a change to that collection when a new record is added to the database via the second View.

Is there a sample implementation out there somewhere, or can someone provide the basics to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you post your xaml binding code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make `lstArtists` type ObservableCollection where T is your model.

Whenever you make change to the database, you have to fire a global scope event, there are many ways, but I use Messenger from MVVM Light. In the event handler you make change to the `lstArtists` to have it in sync with database.

Please remember that you have to bind thte `ItemsSource` property of the ListView to the public property name `lstArtists`

Comment: Thanks, I had completely forgotten about the MVVM Light Messenger.  Have added it to the solution, and now everything works well.